# build my own project with ASP.NET MVC assemblies

Tags: asp.net-mvc

maybe my question is stupid, but can i build my own project with ASP.NET MVC assemblies from  [this source code?](https://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781)
I want set the break points and study the code step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Obviously you can. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, but the link is ASP.NET MVC 3. The latest version is [MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4)